# *.org domain websites are not loading

Tags: networking, dns, browser, ip, domain

The problem is that any page with *.org domain in not loading on my computer (Ubuntu 14.04). Any other domains like *.com, *.net are loading!

This is very strange. I tried in different browsers, and on my 2nd computer with Windows 7.

For example I try to access http://wordpress.org and the browser doesn't find DNS. I tried also to `ping wordpress.org` and the result is: `ping: unknown host wordpress.org`

This happens with every website that have *.org domain.

I checked on TOR and online proxy and *.org domains are loading properly.

I didn't changed any settings in browser or in my router.

Using this site: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ the result is: `It's just you. http://wordpress.org is up.`

Is my ISP blocking *.org domains? :S

Even `traceroute wordpress.org` returns "Unknown host".

Weird?

Comment: What happens if you enter https://www.eff.org into your browser ?  What about when you enter https://69.50.225.155 (which is the IP address of eff.org)?

Comment: @dazzle https://www.eff.org is loading, loading (probably looking dns) and then firefox returns "Server not found". The IP address is working, it loads the site title but it goes very slow ;o

Comment: Yes! IP equivalents of websites are working properly but domain names... However the loading time is very long.

Comment: What DNS server are you using? What happens if you do a DNS lookup to a `.org` domain against Google DNS (8.8.8.8)?

Comment: @Twisty how to change them? In the router? If yes, `The orange DNS servers are configured by default and can not be modify on the Livebox`. My ISP is orange.

Comment: Thank you guys for help. I called my ISP and this was sth on their side. *.org's are now loading :) However, this was really really weird :P